# Преоброзавание русской речи Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-речи, google-speech-recognition

Для распознование речи использую библиотеку speech_recognition, но она распознает только английскую речь, а мне нужно, чтобы распознавала русскую.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: возможно это вам поможет, посмотрите https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YeS755SPSI8

Comment: @Интик Спасибо! Помогло

Answer (score 0):

[С помощью этой библиотеки из коробки никак](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/pocketsphinx.rst).

> By default, SpeechRecognition's Sphinx functionality supports only US
> English. Additional language packs are also available, but not
> included due to the files being too large:
>
> International French
>
> Mandarin
>
> Chinese
>
> Italian

[Но можно загрузить собственные модели](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst).

> The language parameter can also be a tuple of filesystem paths, of the
> form (acoustic_parameters_directory, language_model_file,
> phoneme_dictionary_file) - this allows you to load arbitrary Sphinx
> models.